# How can I stop this wierd output of my lists in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make each element in a list clickable separately. I have an array of divs which I will loop into an array soon but for simplicity, I just hardcoded them into it(I am going to add more elements once I figure this out). When I click on the list item div, I want it to turn that Item into the text: "clicked".

I want to keep the files separate because this app will get big and I'm planning to add much more.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Comp from './Comp';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    list: [
      "gameplay", 
      "visuals"
    ]

  }

  changetext = event =>{
    this.setState({list: event.target.textContent = "clicked"});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Comp list = {this.state.list}
        changetext = {this.changetext}/> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comp.js

The problem here is that when I click on a list item, The event.target.textContent is inputting {props.list[0]} and {props.list[1]} into the event object and turn both elements into c and l respectively.. both are the first and second elements in the string array "clicked".

The strange thing is, when I click the c or the l the second time, they act as I wanted them to and separately turn into clicking. So the question is, How can I achieve this without the initial hiccup? Let me know if you need set up information.

```
import React from 'react';

const Comp = props => {



    let listarr = [];

        listarr[0] = <div key = {0} onClick = {props.changetext}{props.list[0]}
listarr[1] = <div key = {1} onClick = {props.changetext}>{props.list[1]}
</div>

        return(
            <div>{listarr}</div>

        );
    }

    export default Comp;
```

Comment: I realize my question title was irrelevant. I fixed it.

Comment: In your setState, you are setting whole list array as "clicked" not the way you desired. Just console.log your state and see what I mean. After first click there is no items in list anymore, list is just a string which is "clicked". @SrThompson has given a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors. If you want to change the text to "clicked" you can do it like this:

```
const Comp = props => {
  let listarr = [];
  listarr.push(<div key={0} onClick={props.changetext}>{props.list[0]}</div>);
  listarr.push(<div key={1} onClick={props.changetext}>{props.list[1]}</div>);
  return (
    <div>{listarr}</div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    list: [
      "gameplay",
      "visuals"
    ]

  }

  changetext = event => {
    const { textContent } = event.target;
    // Always use the callback syntax for setState when you need to refer to the previous state
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      list: prevState.list.map(el => textContent === el ? "clicked" : el)
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Comp list={this.state.list}
          changetext={this.changetext} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i ask what that wierd syntax does? const {textContent} = event.target? Otherwise this works great!

Comment: would it be an equivialent if I stored event.target.textContent into a variable?

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's exactly right,  this `const {textContent} = event.target` is equivalent to this `const textContent = event.target.textContent`. It's called destructuring

Answer (score 0):

Just change the method you are passing as a property to be:

```
this.changetext.bind(this)
```

so it will look like this:

```
  <div>
    <Comp list = {this.state.list}
    changetext = {this.changetext.bind(this)}/> 
  </div>
```

Or your other option could be to do this in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.changetext.bind(this);
}

...

render() {
  <div>
    <Comp list = {this.state.list}
    changetext = {this.changetext}/> 
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately after trying this, I get the same result.

Comment: Yes you are because this is not the problem. You are using an arrow function, so there is no need to bind it.